# How to copy/paste all the contents from terminal to notepad using keyboard?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, command-line-interface

I ran a script in 'cygwin' terminal. Now I have more than 10000(10k) line as output. I want to copy all the contents using keyboard, like we have in Windows

```
'ctrl +A' - Select All
'ctrl +c' - Copy
'ctrl +v' - Paste
```

I am aware of doing mouse-over from start to end. But it is a difficult task.

Please suggest me if there is someway to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect the stderr and stdout outputs to a file (similar to as you would see on the terminal), use:

```
mycommand > output_and_error.txt 2>&1
```

This will take the output from your `mycommand` and pipe it into a file called output_and_error.txt  You can then open this text file in Notepad or wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. This option is good. But what if command is already executed, is there any option to copy the contents from terminal directly? And if we use the "mycommand > output_and_error.txt 2>&1" option, we cant see the live logs. Am i right? How to get the output file and see the live logssame time?

Comment: If the command is already executed you are probably going to need to mark/copy/paste.  Maybe press the Up arrow to give you back the last command you ran and append the pipe to file onto it?  As for watching the entries as they appear, see if there's a `tail` equivalent in cygwin (can't remember off the top of my head I'm afraid)